# debug matlab mex file in windows without visual studio

Tags: windows, matlab, debugging, mex

I've looked for some info about how can i debug matlab mex file in Windows without having VS.
unfortunately, the only quick and relevant link (http://info-te.ch/~geli/mexdebug/mexdebug.html) is broken.
I can use eclipse and MinGW, but need assistance to configure it correctly

10x

Comment: Ok, why not...  I don't know about MinGW, but the Windows SDK is free and NOT VS and provides a GUI debugger called WinDbg. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx

Comment: @michaelbezenchuk why venture so far? Can't you install [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-2010-express) or something?

Comment: @michaelbezenchuk why venture so far? Is it a VS licensing problem? Why can't you install VS Express?

Comment: @EitanT, have you tried it before? If so, can I have your assistance to configure it correctly?